# jsPDF Corrupt PDFs?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf

I am trying to create a PDF file with JavaScript using **jsPDF**. I have a little test page. Basically I have a download PDF button that takes the base64 image from a span and uses that for the `imgData`. I then try to `addImage` that image data to the pdf and then save it. Everything seems to work, it generates the PDF and prompts for download. However when I try to look at the PDF with xpdf or Foxit reader I am told the PDF is corrupted. **Am I creating this PDF incorrectly?** My web page is pretty long, so I put it on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/uzyNLybM).

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />   
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jspdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/FileSaver.js/FileSaver.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/BlobBuilder.js/BlobBuilder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jspdf.plugin.addimage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/basic.js"></script>
<title>Sup!</title>
<script>
function changeCan() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,128,128);
}
function changeCan3() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,128,128);
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = document.getElementById("3span").innerHTML;
  ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
}
function changeCan4() {
  var imgData = document.getElementById("3span").innerHTML;
  window.alert(imgData.length);
  var doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 128, 128);
  doc.save('Test.pdf');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  Yo!<hr>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="128" height="128"></canvas><hr>
  <button type="button" onClick="changeCan()">Change Me To Red!</button>
  <button type="button" onClick="changeCan3()">Change Me To Span!</button>
  <button type="button" onClick="changeCan4()">Download Me!</button>
  <hr>
  <span id="3span" style="display:none;">B64 DATA HERE</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your `3span` DIV, the innerHTML contains `data:image/jpeg;base64,`. Is it required/necessary? Just a thought, I don't know this jsPDF lib, but I am interested, I will need this pretty soon :)

Comment: Well the `data:image/jpeg;base64,` portion seems nessecary for a different part of the test page I was fooling around with, that was changing the canvas to the laughing man graphic. Also on the jsPDF web page, http://jspdf.com/ , the example with the cat image shows the `data:image/jpeg;base64,` "header" if you will. @JScoobyCed So i'm not totally certain if it's needed or not, I can try to remove it quick and generate another PDF!

Comment: @JScoobyCed I quick removed that chunk of info from the base64 data and both the canvas and PDF errored out. I'm not too worried about the canvas, that's just for chuckles. The PDF though did not work, here's the error FireBug spit, `getJpegSize could not find the size of the image
[Break On This Error] throw new Error('getJpegSize could not find the size of the image'); ` I looked at the code in the .js file from his library and I can't really tell exactly what it's doing. Grabbing certain chars, getting lengths and doing some math with that info.

Comment: I tried your code and all it generates in the PDF is this text:`[object Uint8Array]`. So I guess it's not corrupted but something not generated fully. Can't help more than that I need to read about jsPDF first and can't do that now. Good luck.

Comment: Hey thanks for the try! That was probably the alert, use it a bit for debugging :) Good luck to you in the future as well.

Comment: I misread your comment about trying the code @JScoobyCed , I looked at the PDF and saw what you were talking about. I must simply be missing something in how i'm handling the base64 data or something... when I figure it out i'll post an answer! Hopefully you won't have much trouble when you consider implementing jsPDF :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had similar problem, and this is how is solved it. I used [Blob.js](https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js), [canvas-toBlob](https://github.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js), [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/). I also noticed that latest BlobBuilder.min.js is not working correcly, so I used BlobBuilder.js instead.

```
var content = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
var doc = new jsPDF('landscape');
doc.addImage(content, 'JPEG', 0, 0);

var data = doc.output();
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(data.length);
var array = new Uint8Array(buffer);

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    array[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
}

var blob = new Blob(
    [array],
    {type: 'application/pdf', encoding: 'raw'}
);

saveAs(blob, filename);
```

Comment: Very concise, I will give this a test when I have some time after work! One question though, at the beginning you grab content from a canvas, in my scenario the pictures load are from the local machine. (A script generates the webpage and the image data for it). If I already have the DataURL defined in a span, could I simply go " var content = getElementByID("SPANID").innerHtml " ? The inner html is the toDataURL ASCII generated by the script. Thanks for the great answer, I will definitely look into your method and see how it pans out!

Comment: I was testing your solution, but I get a pdf like **name.pdf-1.part** is there a way I can just get **name.pdf**?

Comment: I haven't found a way to get rid of the .part extension. I think my version of FireFox (12) just wasn't at all compatible with jsPDF. I upgraded my FireFox to version 18.0.2 and my original script worked, it still had that .part extension though. I am not sure why it does that. Must be something on the library side. It is unfortunate because i'd like to be able to offer some cross-browser compatibility for my webpage. I might have to setup my clients to use the latest FireFox I guess. There has been alit of issues submitted on the jsPDF github. Perhaps we will get a nice update!

Comment: @Jeff Also, I wanted to add a little bit of general purpose info. If you are looking to generate a PDF file, there was a website I read where someone manually built a PDF file with just his text editor. I haven't tried it yet, but it may be very possible to create your own little function to create some PDFs on the client side, depending on how adventurous you are and how dynamic your PDFs would be. http://mariomalwareanalysis.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-manually-create-pdf.html I haven't tested his method but it might be a start if you want to get adventurous ;)

Comment: That .part extensions is really funky :) Do you use any extension/addon for download in FF? Can you test it in Chrome? What OS are you using?

Comment: @mtasic85 No I don't use any extension for download, use the usal way, I use Linux.

Answer (score 2):

I used the 1.3.4 version of jsPDF and it worked

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem using **png** image type : PDF was corrupted when opened with Adobe Reader.

Changing it to **jpeg** resolved it !

```
// Before : Corrupted PDF file when opened with Adobe Reader
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
doc.addImage(imgData, 'png', 0, 0, 210, 295);

// After : Working
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
doc.addImage(imgData, 'jpeg', 0, 0, 210, 295);
```